# View methods of Node.js String.prototype?

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

In the Node.js REPL, if you type `String.prototype`, an empty object: `{}` is returned. But if you type it in the Chrome JavaScript console, an object is returned with the expected function names and functions.

Why doesn't Node.js exhibit this behavior? How can I access the native String functions in Node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the IRC users on FreeNode/#node.js

> BennyLava: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype)
>
> jmar777: because in the REPL you basically get the result of calling `toString()` on the result, whereas the chrome console has some fancy interactive display of objects
>
> BennyLava: they're just not enumerable

So the answer is `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype)`.

Comment: Really? Logging an object works fine - you don't get `[object Object]` as a string.

Comment: @pimvdb Oh, regarding the jmar777 comment? Ya, I think it has to do with the fact that they're not enumerable, and that's why they don't show up.

Comment: @pimvdb: That's because `console.log` [doesn't just print the argument's `toString`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.8.9/lib/util.js#L23).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) to get the Inspector experience for Node.

[image: node-inspector]