# console.log and util.inspect are not printing an object correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log, hexo

In only a specific object, when I use `console.log` or I print the result of `util.inspect` I got just the number `1` or `2` as the result.

How do I now that the object printed is not just the number `1` or `2`? 
I use the debugger inspector to see the attributes and functions, also it's possible to run some code to check all the members of the object, described in [Node.js console.log(object) prints empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941243/node-js-console-logobject-prints-empty-object).

**NOTE:** I tried to clone/copy the object and I'm getting the same behavior, what's is wrong with that object?

I'm using this library:
https://hexo.io/

When I tried to use this feature:
https://hexo.io/api/renderer.html

Code example:

```
hexo.extend.renderer.register('some', 'html', function (data, options, callback) {

    console.log("Data");
    console.log(data); // It works (object is printed sucessfully)
    console.log("Options");
    console.log(options); // I got "2" printed.

    // something unrelated code to use the callback

}, false);
```

Like I said the object `options` have several different members, and is the same/similar behavior with `util.inspect`, even if I specified depth and/or other parameters.

My purpose is to find why does it happen, and how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

In addition, if I try to serialize this object into JSON, using `JSON.stringify`, that's the exception that I'll receive:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
```

Comment: I don't know how to help you, but have you tried to see the typeof() the options? This could clean things up.

Comment: @RodrigoSouza the result is object.

Comment: What does `console.log(arguments)` print?

Comment: try to alter the function parameter name `function (data_r, options_r, callback_r) {` then `console.log(options_r);` what came out?

Comment: @laggingreflex I got just a number for that buggy object, the same behavior as reported. For the other arguments, the objects are printed normally.

Comment: @aswzen same behavior, the second argument always is printed incorrectly.

Comment: maybe its a bug from hexo itself... try to use another version of hexo or look up your code above the register maybe you just set the value to 2, that is all i can help

Comment: So just to review, this code: `console.log(typeof options, options, options.prop)` (where prop is a known property) will print: `object 2 propvalue` Is that right? If so, I must say it's very weird.

Comment: I would dig through the hexo source in node_modules to find where that `hexo.extend.renderer.register` is defined because it must be generating that `options` object to see what its doing to it.

Comment: @laggingreflex thanks for the help. The result of ``console.log(typeof options, options, options.cache)`` was ``object 2 false``  I believe that the problem is some circular structure inside of that object. It will require some tests in separated environment just with ``console.log`` to see how it behaves