# JS in Sublime Text 3 with Node.js Build system

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3, build-system

I'm executing JS code in sublime text 3 with Node 9.4.0 as build system. I would like to know why when I run:

```
function Person () {     }

var manu = new Person();

console.log(Person.prototype)
```

I get:

```
Person {}
```

But when I run it from Chrome console, I get:

```
{constructor: ƒ}
  constructor: ƒ Person()
  __proto__: Object
```

How can I get Node to display the content of ***Person.prototype*** ?

Why does it display it empty?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to another [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536510/view-methods-of-node-js-string-prototype), it looks like you could do something like

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person.prototype))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here no need to use **"new"** keyword you can run it as simple function.But
>   for **"new"** keyword it will convert it as constructor hence Person.prototype
>   is referring superior object which is window if you are running in
>   console that convert it as constructure

For Exp:-

```
function Person () {     }

var manu = new Person();

//var manu = Person();
```